# Subtracting and comparing Dates

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have found some similar Que's on *SO* but had not find the solution.

I have today's `Date` as following: (Let's say this as **Date1** and it's value as `2012-06-22`)

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date start = cal.getTime();
    String currentDate=dateformatter.format(start);
```

---

I'm retrieving 4 values from the user:

- Particular Date (Assume `5`)
- Particular Month (Assume `1`)
- Particular Year (Assume `2012`)
- No. of days (Assume `7`)

So this date, say **Date2** becomes `2012-01-05` (*yyyy-MM-dd*) along with **No. of days** set to `7`.

---

I want to compare **Date 1** and **Date 2-No. of days**.

I know that by using following snippet, particular no. of days can be subtracted from a calender instance.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
```

But since I'm having **Date2** in form of `String`, I'm not able to follow this approach.

Any help appreciated.

### Edit:

From your suggestions, I'll be able to convert `String` to `Date` by using `parse` method of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Now I've 2 `Date` Objects.

- How do I find **Difference** between them in terms of `days`, `months`, and `years`?
- How to **Subtract** particular no. of days, say `7`, from a particular date, say `2012-01-05`?

Comment: jodatime will make yr life easier http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert `String` (representing date) to `Date`

For example :

```
Date parsedDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-01-05");
```

Comment: Please have a look at Edited question.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances and to do Date arithmetic use `Calendar` and its   `add()`method See its documentation

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

The question and the accepted answer have used the `java.util` Date-Time API and their parsing/formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` which was appropriate thing to do using the standard library in 2012. In March 2014, Java 8 introduced the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) which supplanted the legacy API and since then it is highly recommended to use the modern Date-Time API.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to** `java.time` **(JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.**

### Requirements copied from your question:

> From your suggestions, I'll be able to convert `String` to `Date` by using
> parse method of `SimpleDateFormat`.
>
> Now I've 2 `Date` Objects.
>
> - How do I find Difference between them in terms of `days`, `months`, and
>   `years`?
> - How to Subtract particular no. of days, say `7`, from a
>   particular date, say `2012-01-05`?

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

With `java.time`, you can parse your date string into a `LocalDate` and then find the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) between this date and the current date (which you obtain with `LocalDate.now()`). You can also subtract days, months, and years using methods like `minusXxx`/`minus`. You have similar methods (`plusXxx`/`plus`) for adding these units. Check [the documentation of `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) to learn more about it.

**Note**: `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `2012-06-22`).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate then = LocalDate.parse("2012-06-22");
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

        Period period = Period.between(then, now);
        System.out.println(period);
        System.out.printf("%d years %d months %d days%n", 
           period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays());

        // Examples of subtracting date units
        LocalDate sevenDaysAgo = now.minusDays(7);
        System.out.println(sevenDaysAgo);
        // Alternatively
        sevenDaysAgo = now.minus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(sevenDaysAgo);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
P10Y6M27D
10 years 6 months 27 days
2023-01-11
2023-01-11
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/40NmZn)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

If you can *possibly* use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `Date`/`Calendar`, do so. It'll make your life easier.

If not, it sounds like you don't want to *format* the current date - instead, you want to *parse* `Date2` from the user:

```
Date date2 = dateFormatter.parse(text);
```

Then you can *either* create a calendar and subtract a particular number of days, or (if you're talking about elapsed time - you need to think about your behaviour around DST transitions and time zones here) you could just subtract 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds from `date2.getTime()`.

Fundamentally, you should convert *out* of a string format as earlier as possible, and only convert *to* a string format when you really need to - certainly not for comparisons. The natural representation of this data is as a `Date` or `Calendar` (assuming you're sticking with the JDK), so work towards getting your data into that representation.

You have several genuine "business" questions to think about though:

- Do you want to compare the current *date* with the date the user's given, or the current *date and time* with the date the user's given?
- What time zone do you want to use for the user's input?
- Are you thinking about elapsed days or "logical" days? Because 7 * 24 hours earlier than 1.30am may be 2.30am or vice versa, due to DST transitions

You should answer all those questions *before* you try to implement your code, as it will affect the representation you use. Also, write unit tests for everything you can think of before you start the implementation.

Comment: TimeZone for both the dates are same so no issue about transition. I want to compare today's date with a specific date (which will be created from string using parse method).

Comment: Please have a look at Edited question.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you have two dates now and you want to subtract a particular number of days from date.

First you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert a date to string and string to date

Now to subtract days say 7. you can get time of the date and subtract 7*24*60*60*1000 from it

```
     long daybeforeLong = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
try {

Date todayDate = new Date();

long nowLong = todayDate.getTime();

Date beforeDate = new Date((nowLong - daybeforeLong));

    } 

catch (ParseException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of Comparator provided by java will do work of comparing and sorting the dates too.
here is the [link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CompareDate.shtml)

hope you get what you was looking for..

Comment: Please have a look at Edited question.